# Is it practical to have both Python 2.7 and 3.3 installed at the same time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am using pip to pull down libraries but didnt realize the key one is only for 2.7.  So now I am working in the 2.7 directory but pip is still installing libs in 3.3. So pyCharm keeps saying the lib is missing.

I have the PATH var set (this is *gasp* fn windows 8) so that Python 2.7 comes first but i think the python exe isn't looking in the first place I had pip install things.  Maybe there is a setting in pip that will install it elsewhere now?

Any hints on how to make this work would be great.  Maybe I just need to start over w/o python 3.3?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: check out virtualenv -- it might take some doing to get it working for pycharm, but it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Just about every (recent) Debian and Ubuntu box has both. My main box also has 2.6 and 3.2 from prior releases.

Comment: Note that you can also launch pip as `pip-X.Y`, where `X.Y` is the python version. (This may require to install `pip` for each version) [at least on linux, but should be the same on windows too]

Comment: [python launcher](http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) makes it easier to run Python scripts for different versions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these two solutions:

1)Remove python3.3 from the path variable and try installing library using pip now. so that pip from python27 can install things.

2)if this doesn't work then use

> C:\python27\Scripts\pip.exe install

Answer (score 0):

Oh My Crap, this is so easy.  Thank you to AMWinter for this:
http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html

It seems to manage all this chaos of the Python version (and library versions) for me easy.  Of course I needed to tell it the python version (with flag -p) but that was it.

(although it did not put pip where it said it would - just pls note)

Dirk and Bakuriu are appreciated as well.  Like Ruby, I realize managing versioning is a necessary evil.

Thank you all!